# What decides Liquibase changeset execution order

Tags: sql, database, liquibase

I have Googled a bit and all I have found is that the order of changeset executions depends on their order in the file they are placed.

Below is a list of changesets in the same file:

```
<changeSet id="A" author="abc">
</changeset>
<changeSet id="B" author="abc">
</changeset>
```

Is the order of execution decided based on *id* or the order in which they are placed? Also, what if the `<changeSet>` are in different files, what will be the order of execution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Order of execution is based on changeset order (position they are placed) in the file.
Usually it is the order they should be executed.

If you load two or more files, all changesets from the first file will be executed, then from second etc...
You can create file based on release, some tags etc..

Comment: Maybe the changes get applied sequentially by changeSet id. At least that seems implied here, if I follow correctly: http://www.liquibase.org/get-started/running-your-first-update.

Answer (score 2):

The order of execution of the scripts for a normal update operation is just like Lemmy gave above. But, if you modified some scripts and the changeset has the "runOnChange" attribute set to true, then when you execute the update operation, it will only execute only those modified or updated changesets - again going by the same order as described by Lemmy.

Now, If you perform a rollback operation, I have noticed that the changesets that got executed in the "second run" which only executed those "runOnChange" changesets - they get executed first. So it looks like the rollback will not happen based on the descending order of the original changeset execution - rather its based on the descending order of the timestamp of when the changesets got executed.   This might cause the rollback sqls to fail if there are "dependencies" that were created in the later part of the scripts in the original run. I think this might be a bug in liquibase wrt the rollback behavior or maybe it was intentional.